# How to suppress PMD warnings during a Maven install

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, pmd, suppress-warnings

I have a Java project that is built using **Maven**, thus my build process is defined in the *pom.xml* file of the project. My development team uses a variety of plugins to check the quality of our source code; one such plugin uses **[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)** to check the code.The plugin makes sure that PMD is run every time we execute `mvn install` on the project and it will fail the build if there is a violation. Here is the plugin in our pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                <linkXref>false</linkXref>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <failurePriority>1</failurePriority>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>config/pmd-rulesets.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

My problem is that there are some times -- especially when I am in the middle of developing a task and I want to check out if my code builds, but before I am ready to submit my source code to the SCM for automatic build and release to others -- when I will want to suppress PMD violations from failing my build. I know that one such solution is to go into the code and add annotations to suppress warnings (http://pmd.sourceforge.net/suppressing.html), but I believe that editing source code in this way just to suppress these violations is annoying and error-prone. Another thing I could do is edit my pom and comment out the PMD plugin. However, once again, I find changing a file that is essential to my overall application is annoying and error-prone.

The solution that my team desires for is one that allows us to simply pass in some sort of flag or argument into our `mvn` command to quickly tell the build process to skip the PMD plugin. For example, whenever we are running an install at a point in the development phase and we know that the integration tests will probably fail (like, a web service may not be active), we pass the `-Dskip.integration.tests=true` flag during `mvn install`. This is a much cleaner solution than having to edit our test files or change pom.xml. I am looking for a similar variable to allows us to quickly skip PMD violations. Thanks!

**PS**: I did my homework. The following two Stackoverflow questions did not contain my desired solution:

- [PMD with Maven - How to disable one rule within a ruleset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147938/pmd-with-maven-how-to-disable-one-rule-within-a-ruleset)
- [PMD - How to exclude files from violation check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769641/pmd-how-to-exclude-files-from-violation-check)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just declare failPmdOnViolation property in your pom.xml as true, specify that property in plugin settings instead of hardcoded constant and then you can override it by activating a special profile of from the command line. Or you can refer [default expression for failOnViolation plugin property](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/check-mojo.html#failOnViolation) like `mvn -Dpmd.failOnViolation=false install`

Answer (score 20):

I used below command the same way we use `skipTests=true`.

```sh
mvn clean install -Dpmd.skip=true
```

Also for findbugs we can use

```
-Dfindbugs.skip=true
```